# Getting R to interact with an external application

Tags: r

I have an R script that used to be used on standalone CSV files but now needs to accept similar inputs from another, existing application. What are the typical options to call R from an external application written in Python and to pass data to it?

As a toy example, you could imagine a web application written in Python that needs to  send R a dataset and then the R script calculates summary stats and sends back to the application. The size of the input dataset is small. Think of it as one row from a database with approx. 20 fields. The fields are a mix of text and numbers. The number of fields is fixed in this call. In the earlier flow these fields were members of a CSV file line.

Example:

```
New York, 23456,,25.5, 23/04/2015,, 0, 0, Yes, Yes, Absent
```

The return from R is something like:

```
0.87, Demographics, NA, History, NA
```

PS. I don't mean something like Shiny-R which provides both the front end and back end. Here the external application is pre-existing but just needs a way to call R with its data and get a result back.

Comment: This is a very broad question, you should revise it to address specific use cases.

Comment: ^agreed. In the  general case most applications have a way to interact with the command line, which you can run R scripts from.

Comment: @Chris  Ok, I will edit this and add details

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the rpy2 package from Python to allow the usage of R-Commands and Functions in a python script rather than send and receiving data back and forth to R.

[rpy2 main website](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/)

[Here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/rpy2.html) is a nice tutorial on rpy2.

Comment: Thanks! One reason this seems not ideal is that I want to minimize changes to the external Python Application as things proceed. The intention is to freeze the format of the data sent but after that any tweaking can be done at the R end without having to fiddle with the external application written in Python. e.g. Say I change the return value from a RMS average to a median or mode I want to be able to do that change at the R end without modifying the Python code.

Comment: With rpy2 you can use python to handle the communication as well (from flask to twisted or zmq). Moreover rpy2 is able to handle R scripts as if they were Python modules.  Check: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.6/html/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-arbitrary-r-code-as-a-package

Answer (score 1):

Have a deeper look at : [`Rserve`](https://rforge.net/Rserve/)